# Toggle + white border when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I need the functions that currently show the hidden blocks when clicked on a block, to toggle between the hidden classes instead. Also when clicked on a block, a white border needs to appear to show which block has been chosen and when clicked on the same block again, the white border needs to disappear. When I tried changing the code to let it toggle, it didn't toggle at all. I also can't seem to figure out how to add a white border when a block is clicked and removed once the block is clicked again. How can I fix this?

I have tried changing "remove" to "toggle" in my JavaScript code, but it's not toggling.

What I was expecting: When I click on the block called "main" in "choice 1" the row with blocks has to show in "choice 2", but when I click on the block "main" again, it has to hide the blocks again.
This the same for the other blocks in "choice 3" and "choice 4". Also, once clicked on a block, it has to show a white border and when clicked on the same block again, the white border needs to disappear.

[image]

The function code is the same for the other showHiddenblocks. I just added the numbers to 2, 3a, 4a, etc.

```js
function showHiddenBlocks() {
  const hiddenBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block2.hidden');
  hiddenBlocks.forEach((block) => {
    block.classList.remove('hidden');

  });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block2" onclick="showHiddenBlocks()">
  <p>Main</p>
</div>

<div class="block2 hidden" onclick="showHiddenBlocks2()" style="background-color:hotpink;">
  <p>Pink</p>
</div>
<div class="block2 hidden" onclick="showHiddenBlocks3a()" style="background-color:orange;">
  <p>Orange</p>
</div>
<div class="block2 hidden" onclick="showHiddenBlocks4a()" style="background-color:lightblue;">
  <p>Lightblue</p>
</div>
<div class="block2 hidden" onclick="showHiddenBlocks5a()" style="background-color:green;">
  <p>Green</p>
</div>
<div class="block2 hidden" onclick="showHiddenBlocks6a()" style="background-color:blue;">
  <p> Blue</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You aren't attempting to do much of what you describe in your example. You need to make an effort and show it, not just ask us to do it for you. Also you _do not_ need separate functions for every element. Learn how to pass a value to _one_ function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you need:

```js
function showHiddenBlocks() {
  const hiddenBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block2.hidden');
  hiddenBlocks.forEach((block) => {
    block.classList.remove('hidden');
  });
}

function onClick(event) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.block2').forEach(block => {
    if (block.contains(event.target))
      block.classList.add("border")
    else
      block.classList.remove("border")
  })
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.border {
  border: thick solid #000
}
```

```html
<div class="block2" onclick="showHiddenBlocks()"><p>Main</p></div>

<div class="block2 hidden" onclick="onClick(event)" style="background-color:hotpink;"><p>Pink</p></div>
    <div class="block2 hidden" onclick="onClick(event)" style="background-color:orange;"><p>Orange</p></div>
    <div class="block2 hidden" onclick="onClick(event)" style="background-color:lightblue;"><p>Lightblue</p></div>
    <div class="block2 hidden" onclick="onClick(event)" style="background-color:green;"><p>Green</p></div>
    <div class="block2 hidden" onclick="onClick(event)" style="background-color:blue;"><p> Blue</p></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, but it's not what I meant. The border around the block in the first row needs to stay active once i've clicked a block in the second row and so on for the other rows. Is this explanation clear and can you fix it like that?

Comment: @Frank Are you looking to create a dropdown treeview?